# Unexpected behaviour in code::block

Tags: gcc, codeblocks

I have the following piece of code:

```
nod* fanod() {
  nod* aux = (nod*)malloc(sizeof(nod));
  int i;
  for(i = 0; i < 29; ++i)
          aux->x[i] = NULL;
  //return aux;
}
```

In Code::Blocks 16.01 whether I leave that `return` or delete it, the function still returns `aux`. If I take it out, I get no errors and the program actually works like I intended it too. If I move it to Visual Studio, it obviously only works by adding the `return`, otherwise, it gives off an error.

What is happening here? Is this from the settings of `gcc` or am I missing something?

Comment: (1) Look up **undefined behaviour**. (2) Figure out how to add gcc options in code::blocks, and add something like `-Wall -Wextra -Werror`.

Comment: @n.m. Thanks a bunch! If I got it right: Cases of undefined behaviour produce surprising results when compiled, especially with optimisation enabled.